How can I access the 'Retry-After' HTTP response header while using @solana/web3.js to make RPC requests?
I've been trying to use the @solana/web3.js library to send RPC requests for transaction data but I'm getting hit with the following error:
Error: 429 Too Many Requests:  {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":{"code": 429, "message":"Too many requests for a specific RPC call, contact your app developer or support@rpcpool.com."}
I've realized that the solution lies in the Retry-After HTTP response header. I have to obtain this header to know how long I need to wait for the rest of the requests to execute properly without error. My only problem is that I don't know how to access this response header in @solana/web3.js.
Here are the requests:
function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

async function rpcRequests() {
  try {
    const Signatures = await connection.getSignaturesForAddress(address, options);
    Signatures.forEach(signature => {
        if (signature && signature.signature && signature.err === null) {
            SignaturesArray.push(signature.signature);
        }
    });

    await delay(1000);

    const Transactions = await connection.getParsedTransactions(SignaturesArray, GetVersionedTransactionConfig);
    Transactions.forEach(transaction => {
        if (transaction && transaction.transaction && transaction.transaction.message && transaction.transaction.message.instructions) {
            const instructions = transaction.transaction.message.instructions;
            instructions.forEach(instruction => {
                console.log(instruction);
                }
            })
        }
    })
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error: ' + error);
  }
}

rpcRequests();

(I'm only showing a portion of the code, there are 6 more requests that need to be sent)

This is a great suggestion. We will add this. https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js/issues/3563

If you're currently using the public rpc and getting rate limited, try signing up for a free helius account and use a custom rpc endpoint.
https://www.helius.dev/
